# Running into a 1.7mb limit with CSOM based upload functionality

Tags: javascript, sharepoint-online, csom

Running into the following error when I try to upload files larger than 1.7 MB:

"Request failed with error message - The request message is too big. The server does not allow messages larger than 2097152 bytes. . Stack Trace - undefined"

```
function uploadFile(arrayBuffer, fileName)  
    {  
        //Get Client Context,Web and List object.  
        var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext();  
        var oWeb = clientContext.get_web();  
        var oList = oWeb.get_lists().getByTitle('CoReTranslationDocuments'); 
                     
        
        var bytes = new Uint8Array(arrayBuffer);  
        var i, length, out = '';  
        for (i = 0, length = bytes.length; i < length; i += 1)  
        {  
            out += String.fromCharCode(bytes[i]);  
        }  
        var base64 = btoa(out);  
        
         
        var createInfo = new SP.FileCreationInformation();  
        createInfo.set_content(base64);  
        createInfo.set_url(fileName);  
        
       
        var uploadedDocument = oList.get_rootFolder().get_files().add(createInfo);
        
         
        clientContext.load(uploadedDocument);  
        clientContext.executeQueryAsync(QuerySuccess, QueryFailure);  
        
    }
```

We just switched from SP2013 to Sharepoint Online. This code worked well with even larger files previously. Does the 2MB limit refer to the file being uploaded or the size of the REST request?

I also did read about a possible solution using filestream - is that something I can use in this scenario?

Any suggestions/ modifications to the code will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

SharePoint has its own limits for CSOM. Unfortunately, these limits cannot be configured in Central Administration and also cannot be set using CSOM for obvious reasons.

When googling for the issue, mostly a solution is given by setting the ClientRequestServiceSettings.MaxReceivedMessageSize property to the desired size.

Call the following PowerShell script from SharePoint Management Shell :

```
   $ws = [Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPWebService]::ContentService 
   $ws.ClientRequestServiceSettings.MaxReceivedMessageSize = 209715200 
   $ws.Update()
```

This will set the limit to 200 MB.

However, in SharePoint 2013 Microsoft apparently added another configuration setting to also limit the amount of data which the server shall process from a CSOM request (Why anyone would configure this one differently is beyond me...). After reading a very, very long SharePoint Log file and crawling through some disassembled SharePoint server code, I found that this parameter can be set via the property ClientRequestServiceSettings.MaxParseMessageSize.

We are now using the following script with SharePoint 2013 and it works great:

```
  $ws = [Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPWebService]::ContentService 
  $ws.ClientRequestServiceSettings.MaxReceivedMessageSize = 209715200 
  $ws.ClientRequestServiceSettings.MaxParseMessageSize = 209715200 
  $ws.Update()
```

Hope that saves some people a headache!